# Generate barcode for a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, qr-code, barcode

I have a tricky situation I am stuck at, I am trying to create a route to generate a barcode. On this route, the response should be an SVG image containing a barcode from the document ID. Is there anyone familiar with this and can help me out:

- Is there a package to do this kind of request, and where do i go from here.
- The barcode should contain only the document Id, how do generate it into Code-39.

Below is my my route sample, many thanks in advance!

```js
router.get('/documents/:id/barcode', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const document = await Document.getByIdOrName(req.params.id);
    if (!document) {
     // throw Error
    }
   // Here I need to send a response SVG image 
   // with a generated barcode from the the document Id 

  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
})
```

Comment: Just by a simple google search: https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/

Answer (score 0):

The following library allows you to generate barcodes: [JsBarcode](https://lindell.me/JsBarcode)

To generate one with the Code-39 format. Simply add the following property: `format: 'CODE39'`

```js
JsBarcode("#barcode", "DocumentId", {
  format: "CODE39"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I've been able to create the barcode with svg by following the other two suggestions to use [JsBarcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsbarcode) so I will post the answer here:

```js
router.get('/:id/barcode', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const document = await Document.getById(req.params.id);
    if (!document) {
      throw new NotFoundError(
         // throw error,
      );
    }
    const svgDocument = new DOMImplementation().createDocument('');
    const svg = svgDocument.createElementNS('', 'svg');

    jsBarcode(svg, document.id, {
      xmlDocument: svgDocument,
      format: 'CODE39',
    });
    const barcode = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

    res.send(barcode);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```